# find the frequency of each word in two list python

Tags: python

I have two lists which have some bacteria name and other have research abstract I have to find the frequency of bacteria in to  list of the abstract name list

```
example list:-

list1 = ['Bac1','Bac2','Bac3','Bac4','Bac5','Bac']
list2 = ['Abstract1','Abstract2','Abstract3','Abstract4','Abstract5','Abstract6']
```

I have to find how many time list1 content are found in list2 abstract1, abctract2 and so on

Comment: Okay, what's your question?

Comment: Do you have a more meaningful example, this one seems to show no such intersection

Comment: ya in list1 there bacteria name and list list2 there is research abstract text

Comment: I guess `'abstract 1'`, `'abstract 2'`, etc. are actually the full text of the abstracts of the articles?

Comment: yes and i have to count the frequency of list1 which is bacteria name in to list2 which is research abstract text

Comment: On a second thought, reading again your question, is still not clear to me if `list2` is the list of the words of a single abstract, or a list of several abstracts.

Comment: List2 is the full abstract like paragraph of a story

Comment: Ah, it's more simple than I thought then. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the `list1` and use `count()` method in `list2`

**Syntax:**

```
list2.count(element)
```

Where element will be elements from `list1`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

cntwords = Counter(list2)
for bacteria in list1:
    print(f"{bacteria}: {cntwords[bacteria]}") #using formatted string literals, available since python3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the below coding. Let me know that is the expected output for your question.

```
print("List1 is : ",list1)
print("List2 is : ",list2)
for list_1 in list1:
    c=0
    for list_2 in list2:
        if list_1 is list_2:
            c+=1
    if c>0:
        print(list_1 ," frequency is : " ,c)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
List1 is :  ['Bac1', 'Bac2', 'Bac3', 'Bac4', 'Bac5', 'Bac']
List2 is :  ['Abstract1', 'Bac5', 'Bac3', 'Abstract4', 'Bac5', 'Abstract6']
Bac3  frequency is :  1
Bac5  frequency is :  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for this coding?

```
import itertools
list1 = ['Bac1','Bac2','Bac3','Bac4','Bac5','Bac']
list2 = ['ABstract1','ABstract2','ABstract3','ABstract4','ABstract5','ABstract6']
n_list=[]
n_list1=[]
start_B=[]
end_c=[]
for s in list2:
    t=list(itertools.permutations(s,4))
    t3=list(itertools.permutations(s,3))
    for i in range(0,len(t)):
        element =''.join(t[i])
        n_list.append(element)
    for i in range(0,len(t3)):
        ele =''.join(t3[i])
        n_list1.append(ele)
for i in n_list:
    if i.startswith('B') and (i.endswith('1') or i.endswith('2') or i.endswith('3') or 
                              i.endswith('4') or i.endswith('5')):
    #if i[0] == 'B':
        start_B.append(i)
for l1_ele in list1:
    c=0
    for n_ele in start_B:
        if l1_ele == n_ele:
            c+=1
    if c!=0:
        print("Frequency of ",l1_ele," is : ",c)
for i in n_list1:
    if i.startswith('B') and (i.endswith('c')):
    #if i[0] == 'B':
        end_c.append(i)
for l1_ele in list1:
    c_3=0
    for n_ele in end_c:
        if l1_ele == n_ele:
            c_3+=1
    if c_3!=0:
        print("Frequency of ",l1_ele,"  is : ",c_3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Frequency of  Bac1  is :  1
Frequency of  Bac2  is :  1
Frequency of  Bac3  is :  1
Frequency of  Bac4  is :  1
Frequency of  Bac5  is :  1
Frequency of  Bac   is :  6
```